# pushing to master it locks one my folder on github

Tags: github, git-push

I have mother folder contain 3 different folders, I have pushed the parent folder to my github repository but on of three folders is locked,

I was following instruction on this website [initialize a git repo, push to Github](https://gist.github.com/startupstella/2520054/a1423abbf66cc01bd4dfcf3d133d73e341d1fd12)

folder called borroup is locked. 
here is an image to the github

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "locked" you mean you cannot click on it and see its content, check if that same `borroup` folder has, locally on your machine (from where you pushed) a `.git` subfolder.

That would make `borroup` a nested Git repo, which is referenced as a gitlink by the parent repo.

Comment: You right I was able to turn on all hidden files and there was a nested Git repo. I deleted then I tried again it worked.